# Loop Through Specific XML Node and Update VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have some XML formatted like this:

```
<PolicyInput>
  <Header>
    ....
  </Header>
  <Policies>
    <Policy>
      <PolicyRecordNumber>1</PolicyRecordNumber>
      <PCAdjustment>
        ....
      </PCAdjustment>
    </Policy>
    <Policy>
      <PolicyRecordNumber>1</PolicyRecordNumber>
      <PCAdjustment>
        ....
      </PCAdjustment>
    </Policy>
    <Policy>
      <PolicyRecordNumber>1</PolicyRecordNumber>
      <PCNewBusiness>
        ....
      </PCNewBusiness>
    </Policy>
  </Policies>
  <Trailer>    
    <PolicyRecordCount>1</PolicyRecordCount>
  </Trailer>
</PolicyInput>
```

I wish to loop through and update each `PolicyRecordNumber` element in a `For Each` statement and then update the final `PolicyRecordCount` element with the final `PolicyRecordNumber` value.  So, basically, I will update each `PolicyRecordNumber` with `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` and then `5` would be my `PolicyRecordCount` at the end.

How would I do this with VB.NET, as the XML is already formed within the application at this point.

Comment: You say that the XML is "already formed within the application".  Are you saying that it's still in memory, or has it already been written to disk?  If it is still in memory, how is it loaded?  As a `String`?  An `XDocument`, `XmlDocument`, or something else?

Comment: @StevenDoggart As a string, but obviously perfectly transferable to an XMLDocument to then write to File.

Answer (score 0):

Using xelement you can iterate the PolicyRecordNumber individually.  Here is a test.  The first part shows how to read and/or use xelement literals for testing.  At the end the code shows how to accomplish your goal.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Dim yourpath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    'yourpath = IO.Path.Combine(yourpath, "test.xml")

    Dim xe As XElement
    ' to load from a file
    'xe = XElement.Load(yourpath)
    ' for testing
    xe = <PolicyInput>
             <Header>
                 <!-- ... -->
             </Header>
             <Policies>
                 <Policy>
                     <PolicyRecordNumber>1</PolicyRecordNumber>
                     <PCAdjustment>
                         <!-- ... -->
                     </PCAdjustment>
                 </Policy>
                 <Policy>
                     <PolicyRecordNumber>1</PolicyRecordNumber>
                     <PCAdjustment>
                         <!-- ... -->
                     </PCAdjustment>
                 </Policy>
                 <Policy>
                     <PolicyRecordNumber>1</PolicyRecordNumber>
                     <PCNewBusiness>
                         <!-- ... -->
                     </PCNewBusiness>
                 </Policy>
             </Policies>
             <Trailer>
                 <PolicyRecordCount>1</PolicyRecordCount>
             </Trailer>
         </PolicyInput>

    Dim prn As Integer = 1
    For Each el As XElement In xe...<PolicyRecordNumber>
        el.Value = prn.ToString
        prn += 1
    Next
    prn -= 1
    xe.<Trailer>.<PolicyRecordCount>.Value = prn.ToString

    ' to save file
    ' xe.Save(yourpath)
End Sub
```